# How to launch a Machine Learning model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, prediction

First of all thank you for taking your time to read my question. I have done a Machine Learning model with a dataset (The famous one about Cancer) and I want to know how can I do to predict the results for new variables. I think that I have to keep training the data (often) to have more accured data to use in my prediction but for predicting new data, ¿Is as simple as changing the test data (y variable) to the new data?
Thank you so much for taking your time and any help would be appreciate it.

Comment: I recommend you to ask this question here instead https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What model do you use?

Comment: @markuscosinus I used Suppor Vector Machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using the `SVC` class from `sklearn.svm`.
After fitting the model with the `fit` method you can predict new data with the `predict` method. See [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC).

By the way: For Support Vector Machines you don't have to fit your data multiple times. Maybe you are confusing that with neural networks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking in the sense that you are changing the number of features in your test data then you cannot do that.

The number of features has to be the same in training and test set.
However, if your test data have some class of categorical variable which was not there in training data then its better you train your model with one extra category as "NONE" of "Others" for all your features.

This way when you encounter new class of categorical variable in your test data then you changed it to "NONE" or "Others" and do prediction on your trained model.

This way it will not break your model.

I hope I understand your question correctly.